# PHP Multidimension array remove index key and combine

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as below. I need new array without indexing key (0,1,2) and combine array which have duplicate subject.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [email] => Array
            (
                [subject] => subjecting
                [to] => testemail@gmail.com
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [email] => Array
            (
                [subject] => bothsubject
                [to] => textmail@gmail.com
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [email] => Array
            (
                [subject] => bothsubject
                [to] => textmail11@gmail.com
            )

    )

 )
```

Output should be as below

```
  [email] => Array
            (
                [subject] => subjecting
                [to] => testemail@gmail.com
            )
            [email] => Array
            (
                [subject] => bothsubject
                [to] =>textmail@gmail.com, textmail11@gmail.com
            )
```

I have tried array_map function, foreach loop, unfortunately no idea how to execute.

Comment: You can't, Array keys are unique, you cannot have two `$array['key']` at the same level in the array.

Comment: So you have a 3 dimensional array that you want to be just modified 2 dimensional array?

Comment: you can get like `$final_data = array('email'=>array('0'=>array('subject' =>'bothsubject','to' =>'textmail@gmail.com, textmail11@gmail.com'),1=>.....so on))`

Comment: Bhavesh please check all the answers and which one is more suitable , just mark and up-vote that answer. you can up-vote others too if they are helpful too.

Comment: No response from peoples

Answer (score 0):

You may use an intermediate array with subjects as key:

```
$source = array(
    array(
        'email' => array(
            'subject' => "subjecting",
            'to' => 'bharat@intricare.net',
            )
        ),
    array(
        'email' => array(
            'subject' => 'bothsubject',
            'to' => 'textmail@gmail.com'
            )
        ),
    array(
        'email' => array(
            'subject' => 'bothsubject',
            'to' => 'textmail11@gmail.com'
            )
        )
    );

$subjects = array();
foreach ($source as $item) {
    $to = $item['email']['to'];
    $subject = $item['email']['subject'];

    if (isset($subjects[$subject]))
        $to = implode(',', array($subjects[$subject], $to));

    $subjects[$subject] = $to;
}

$result = array();
foreach ($subjects as $subject => $to) {
    $result[] = array(
        'email' => array(
            'subject' => $subject,
            'to' => $to
        )
    );
}
```

Output: https://eval.in/538532